# C errors - Cannot combine with previous 'struct' declaration specifier && Redefinition of 'MyMIDINotifyProc' as different kind of symbol

Tags: c, coremidi

I'm still new to C but trying to understand it better by working my way through a small MIDI audio unit (in Xcode 4.3.3).  I've been searching for an answer to this all day and still don't even understand exactly what the problem is.  Here's the code in question:

```
//MyMIDINotifyProc.h

#ifndef MIDIInstrumentUnit_CallbackProcs_h
#define MIDIInstrumentUnit_CallbackProcs_h

void MyMIDINotifyProc (const MIDINotification *message, void *refCon);

#endif


//MyMIDINotifyProc.c

#include <CoreMIDI/CoreMIDI.h>
#include "MyMIDINotifyProc.h"

void MyMIDINotifyProc (const MIDINotification *message, void *refCon) {
//manage notification
}
```

In the header definition I get this:

```
! Cannot combine with previous 'struct' declaration specifier
```

I've made sure the definitions match and tried renaming them and I still get this in my .c file:

```
! Redefinition of 'MyMIDINotifyProc' as different kind of symbol
```

Which points to the .h definition as the 'Previous definition'.

I know that MIDIServices.h in the CoreMIDI framework defines:

```
typedef void
(*MIDINotifyProc)(const MIDINotification *message, void *refCon);
```

But I don't understand if/why that would cause an error. I would be grateful if anyone could offer some help.

Comment: Aren't you including `<CoreMIDI/CoreMIDI.h>` in your header?

Comment: Wow.  Thanks.  Why did that throw up those errors?

Comment: Posted as an actual answer to shamelessly claim some points ;-)

Comment: No idea how that error came to be, really. It's why I didn't post this as an answer the first time. The error looks quite weird.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include `<CoreMIDI/CoreMIDI.h>` in your `MyMIDINotifyProc.h` header file.

Answer (score 0):

More info here - but I think you are missing the MidiServices.h file where I believe that typedef lives:

http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/CoreMidi/Reference/MIDIServices_Reference/Reference/reference.html

After the first error in the header, the one in the source file becomes meaningless.

```
/*MIDIClientCreate - Creates a MIDIClient object. */

OSStatus MIDIClientCreate (
CFStringRef     name,
MIDINotifyProc  notifyProc,
void            *notifyRefCon,
MIDIClientRef   *outClient
);
```

MIDINotifyProc
Called when the MIDI state changes.

typedef void (*MIDINotifyProc) (
   const MIDINotification  *message,
   void                    *refCon
);

If you named your callback function MyMIDIStateChangedHander, you would declare it like this:

void MyMIDIStateChangedHander (
   const MIDINotification  *message,
   void                    *refCon
);

Parameters
message
Information about the state change.

refCon
The context you provided to the MIDIClientCreate function.

Discussion
The MIDINotifyProc callback function is invoked on the same thread on which you called the MIDIClientCreate function.

Availability
Available in iOS 4.2 and later.
Declared In
MIDIServices.h